# Can "Adaptive Audio" be adjusted on AirPods Pro 2 be adjusted?

Tags: airpods

The new [Adaptive Audio](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213884) feature of [AirPods Pro 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPods_Pro#Second_generation) generally works well.

But I find the *Adaptive Noise Control* sub-feature that blends *Active Noise Cancellation* and *Transparency* modes together has too much transparency and not enough noise cancellation. Too much of the outside is piped into the ear.

Is there any way to adjust that, to increase somewhat the cancelling of noise while in Adaptive Audio mode?